# Float right without changing order, forced shrink

Tags: html, css

This problem is probably quite easy to solve but I'm not sure what I do wrong.

I have the following code:

HTML:

```
<div class='absolute'>
   <div class='container'>
      <span>blabla</span>
      unknown number of spans..
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.absolute{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
.container{
    float: right;
}
span{
    display:block;
    float: left;
}
```

Basically what I want is to have all the spans in one straight line at the bottom right. The absolute div works perfectly and container div float right exactly like I want. The problem is that the spans refuse to line up in one row. I get the following look:
[image]

The red is absolute div, the blue the container div and the green the spans. Well you see my problem..

I have tried to give the container div a width. This result in a straight horizontal line, like the one I want, except that the spans float to the left as far as the width of the blue container div. And I can't calculate the width because I don't know the number of spans.

So how do I solve this without changing any order and without setting a width to the container div? Or rather, why does the container div shrink at all and not just stay as wide as the floats wants it to be?

Thanks for any answer!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AbvJx/ - this works for me as is - something else in your page may be overriding the styles you included in your post.

Comment: Okey, wow. Thanks, that works for me aswell. But now I'm frustrated.. I was sure it wasn't a bug because I couldn't find anything weird in firebug. Oh well I guess I just have to keep looking. Damn.

Answer (score 0):

Change you span to:

```
display: inline-block;
```

should make them go next to each other.
This isn't supported in IE7 or earlier though, if that's important to you, you can do this:

```
display: inline-block; *display: inline;
```

Oh and remove the float left on the span.

Comment: There must be other CSS affecting it then? Have you tried selecting it with firebug and see what is affecting it?

Comment: Did you assign a width property to the container class?

Comment: Okey, this is embarrassing... There was another div around some of the spans that I completely missed. Invisible in the layout so I didn't find it with firebug.. so annoying. Oh well, thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

change display:block to display:inline-block?